# AppleScript: choose color, return color name

Tags: macos, colors, applescript, osx-yosemite, color-codes

What I'm trying to make is this:

```
set retry to true
repeat while retry is true
    display dialog "In the next window you'll have to choose a color!" buttons {"Cancel", "COLORR!"} cancel button 1 default button 2
    
    set Chosencolor1 to (choose color)
    
    
    display dialog "The chosen color is: " & Chosencolor1 & " Is this right?" buttons {"NO", "YES"}
    if the button returned of the result is "no" then
        set retry to true
        display dialog "Retry is now: " & retry
    else
        set retry to false
        display dialog "Retry is now: " & retry
    end if
end repeat
end
```

But when I run this code **it will return a color code as numbers**. But what I want is that it will **return a color name like: light blue, blue, green** etc.

The only way I know is to do something like:

```
if the chosencolor1 is "000" then
set the chosencolor1 to "Black"
end if
end
```

is there any other, more simple way to do this? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the AppleScript Language Guide for **choose color**:

> **Result**   The selected color, represented as a list of three integers
>   from 0 to 65535 corresponding to the red, green, and blue components
>   of a color; for example, {0, 65535, 0} represents green.

As you have surmised, the only way to get a textual response is to program it yourself using the values of the list that your user chooses.

Here is a very simple example that adds all the values of the chosen RGB integers, and determines if it closer to black or white:

```
set myColor to choose color
display dialog ("You have chosen: " & my fetchColorName(myColor))

to fetchColorName(clst)
    set totalColorValue to ((item 1 of clst) + (item 2 of clst) + (item 3 of clst))
    set blackWhiteMidpoint to (196605 / 2)
    if totalColorValue < blackWhiteMidpoint then
        set colorName to "A color closer to black than white."
    else
        set colorName to "A color closer to white than black."
    end if
    return colorName
end fetchColorName
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something like: everything that comes close to the green colorcode will get the name green and everything that comes close to the black colorcode will get the name black? Or is this also not possible? PS: where did you find that Applescript Language Guide? At the developer.apple.com page?

Comment: You can access the **Applescript Language Guide** via the Help Menu in Script Editor.  And yes, with a little logic and some effort, you can easily construct a handler to return a string indicating a color name based on the choice, since the result is a list of the RGB values.  Would you like a short example script?

Comment: ehh yes please :). I just started with applescript so that would be very helpful

Comment: See edited response above.  I am not really adept at understanding RGB values, so you are on your own to figure out more details, but this is the general idea of where you would have to go.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try to search on wikis for the RGB values of the other colors :)